# How to add combined querysets into one template table

Tags: django, django-templates

I have 3 models that are CarDetailsAdd, ShippingDetails, MaintenanceDetails. ShippingDetails and MaintenanceDetails models are connected to CarDetailsAdd foreign-key and each of them have a price field.
here is the problem
[how do I solve this and put data in one row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIJkZ.png)

```
#View
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        profit = CarDetailsAdd.objects.filter(status='sold')
        total_profit = profit.aggregate(Sum('profit_amount'))['profit_amount__sum']
        shipping = ShippingDetails.objects.filter(car__status='sold').values(
            'car').annotate(
            total_shipping_price=Sum('price'))
        maintenance = MaintenanceDetails.objects.filter(car__status='sold').values(
            'car').annotate(
            total_maintenance_price=Sum('price'))
        query = chain(shipping, total_profit, maintenance)
        context = {
            'profit_data': query,
            'total_amount_profit': total_profit,
        }
        return render(request, 'pdf/profit.html', context)
```

```
#template
   <tbody>
      {% for profit_data in profit_data %}
      <tr style="text-align: center">
         <td>{{ profit_data.name }}</td>
         <td>{{ profit_data.purchased_amount }}</td>
         <td>{{ profit_data.total_shipping_price }}</td>
         <td>{{ profit_data.total_maintenance_price }}</td>
         <td>{{ profit_data.sold_details.sold_amount }}</td>
         <td>{{ profit_data.profit_amount }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing now is creating three different queries and simply concatenating them. The result is 3 different objects for each car, because Django does not know which results to combine.

The best way to handle this would be to create one query, and annotate that with the values derived from the relationships. You can annotate a CarDetailsAdd query with values from it's relationship with relationship_name__property.

I'm not sure what your models look like, but assuming that CarDetailsAdd has two many-to-many relationships called shipping_details and maintenance_details, You could do something like this:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    total_profit = profit.aggregate(Sum('profit_amount'))['profit_amount__sum']

    profit = CarDetailsAdd.objects.filter(status='sold')
        .annotate(total_shipping_price=Sum('shipping_details__price')
        .annotate(total_maintenance_price=Sum('maintenance_details__price')

    context = {
        'profit_data': profit,
        'total_amount_profit': total_profit,
    }
    return render(request, 'pdf/profit.html', context)
```